# latex (pdflatex, xelatex, and latex command) seems hanging on error with `-interaction=nonstopmode`

Tags: pdftex, booktabs

The following code will result in command `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex` hanging when encounter the error. Could someone give me some reason?

It only happens when the backslash `\` goes before `\midrule`. If I remove `\midrule`, it works well.

```tex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
% \begin{table}\small
  % \caption{Test the backslash after newline}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
        6050 &   2.06e-05\\
        \ \midrule                            % backslash was before \midrule.
        1038 &   3.37e-06\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
% \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well errors can be so severe that they loop. One reason why I never use nonstopmode. I get a normal error and can stop the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can hit contrl-c (in most systems) to interrupt it and you see

```
! Interruption.
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.13     \end
             {tabular}
?
```

You can stop with `x` at that prompt, but it also shows that this is essentially a repeat of a case that came up the other day

A simpler example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\scrollmode
\begin{document}

{\let\par\relax

x\vskip 2pt

}

\end{document}
```

`\scrollmode` tells TeX not to stop but just do its default error recovery and carry on.

If it sees `\vskip` in horizontal mode, that recovery is to add `\par` to (hopefully) get into vertical mode and then see the skip again.

But if `\par` has been defined to do nothing then adding `\par` does nothing, and so the `\vskip` is again seen in horizontal mode, and `\par` is inserted again for error recovery and it again does nothing....